# How to install same plugin on same site many times

Tags: php, wordpress

How can i install same plugin many times on same site? I am working on a project in which i need to create a plugin using form values.

I am able to create plugin on form submission But now i get to know that we can't install same plugin many times as queries, functions will be same in the plugin.

Is there way to install same plugin?

Comment: If you duplicated everything and renamed everything like class,function and so on, then technically, you should be able to activate them.

Comment: yes..but plugin is made using form values.every time the form is submitted plugin will created which will contain form values bu how can i rename the functions..? for it i need rename them dynamicaly but its making it complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to rename functions programmatically to give them a unique name for each plugin instance. You can do that very easily if you wrap your plugin in a namespace and classes instead of just global functions. Then you would just have to rename the namespace for each instance.

**Read about namespaces in the docs:**

[Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

[Using namespaces: Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)

Comment: yes..but plugin is made using form values.every time the form is submitted plugin will created which will contain form values bu how can i rename the functions..? for it i need rename them dynamicaly but its making it complex

Comment: I assume you copy a template plugin or something when the form is submitted, you would have to substitute the namespace name on the copied plugin instance at the same time.